# Arduino Code Error for blinking LED with user Input

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-uno

I am stuck in some compile time error and not getting the solution for it.

This is the code I have made:

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 Serial.println("How many times you wanna blink the LED?");
 String myString;

 while(myString.equals("")) {
 myString = Serial.readString();
 }

 long int mystring;
 mystring = myString.toInt();
 Serial.print("Okay! the LED will blink ");
 Serial.println(myString);
 Serial.print(" times.");

 Serial.println("In how much time you want the LED to blink once? Please tell the time in milliseconds.");
 String mystr;

 while(mystr.equals("")) {
 mystr = Serial.readString();
 }
 long int myint;
 myint = mystr.toInt();
 Serial.print("Okay we will blink the LED in ");
 Serial.println(myint);
 Serial.print(" milliseconds once.");

 Serial.println("See the Show!!");
 int ms;
 ms = myint / 2;

 while(int i = 0; i < mystring; i++) {
 digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
 delay(ms);
 digitalWrite(13,LOW);
 delay(ms);
}
}
```

and this is the error I am getting again and again.

> Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> D:\ANSH
>   new\Arduino\Blink_LED_user_Input_Times\Blink_LED_user_Input_Times.ino:
>   In function 'void loop()':
>
> Blink_LED_user_Input_Times:36:17: error: expected ')' before ';' token
>
> while(int i = 0; i < mystring; i++) {
>
> ```
>              ^
> ```
>
> Blink_LED_user_Input_Times:36:19: error: 'i' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> while(int i = 0; i < mystring; i++) {
>
> ```
>                ^
> ```
>
> exit status 1 expected ')' before ';' token
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one condition in a `while` [loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_while_loop.htm)

Your syntax looks like you wanted to do a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mystring; i++) { … }
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! You solved the problem and helped me learn my silly mistake.

Comment: No problem. I know that sometimes it is possible to get stuck for long times on "simple" things without a new eye!